# Writes and updates "all or nothing" in DynamoDB

Tags: transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I need to do writes and updates of "all or nothing" in Dynamodb. In the documentation, TransactWriteItems allows this but for 10 or fewer actions.
In my case I can have cases of more than 10 operations of this type.
How can I do "all-or-nothing" operations in this case?

Comment: i doubt if you will be able to do without dynamodb giving you low level apis rather than crud apis.

Comment: You may need to resort to optimistic locking with versioning. Though this documentation is specifically for the Java SDK, the principles are language agnostic. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html